# Goldbach graph using sagemath

Tags: graph, sage, goldbach-conjecture

I'm learning SageMath (uses Python 3)
and playing with the Goldbach conjecture.

I wrote this function (it works!):

```py
def Goldbach(n):
    if n % 2 != 0 or n <= 2:
        show("No és parell")
    else:
        for i in srange(n):
            if is_prime(i):
                for j in srange(n):
                    if is_prime(j) and i + j == n:                        
                        a = [i, j]
                        show(a)
    return
```

Now I'm trying (no idea) to do the following plot:

Denoting by `r(2k)` the number of Goldbach partitions of `2k`,
the conjecture affirms that `r(2k) > 0` if `k > 1`.

I have to do a graph of points `(k, r(2k))`, `k > 2`.
How could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let us get some better implementation in [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org)
of the routine counting the number *r(K)* (for *K > 2* some even integer) of the solutions for *p + q = 2k*, *p*, *q* prime numbers.

We count both solutions *(p, q)* and *(q, p)* when they differ.

```py
def r(K):
    if K not in ZZ or K <= 2 or K % 2:
        return None
    if K == 4:
        return 1
    count = 0
    for p in primes(3, K):
        for q in primes(3, K + 1 - p):
            if p + q == K:
                count += 1
    return count

goldbach_points = [(K, r(K)) for K in range(4, 100,2)]
show(points(goldbach_points))
```

This gives:

[image: Plot of the Goldbach points.]